# translation of Mr. and Mrs. prefix options

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, localisation

So I have to set a translation for the `Mr.` and `Mrs.` prefix options in the `one-page checkout` form, where a customer fills his name, address, etc.

All the translations so far I have done through the `.csv` files or in the template files, but this one I cannot find. Even by turning on the Translation inline for frontend - I cannot see which scope is for these 2 elements. I guess it's the Mage_Customer.csv but it doesn't work from there. Neither from the `translate.csv` file in the design/frontend directory.

Are these optional elements' translations somewhat different? I would appreciate some hints on how to achieve translating this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the options via the admin config section `Customer Configuration->Name and Address Options` then you can set-up each site with different values.

Otherwise by default the block used to translate will belong to `Mage_Customer`. See template /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/widget/name.phtml.

Since these options are set-up via the admin section there is no "default" translations. You could do one of the following options. I think 1 is the easiest, 2 is the one you should not do and 3 is a good option.

1. Add them to your translate.csv file,
2. Add them to Mage_Customer.csv file (please do not do this as these changes will be lost if you update),
3. Create a custom module that deals with customer translations and put them in it's translation file,

Comment: While using the translate.csv option does display them in the right language per store view on the site, the emails and order emails will still have the non-translated default value that you entered in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate prefix in other Language please follow below Steps that translate prefix option in other language in frontend.

**Note: Please installed language pack before these changes.**

Copy:  /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php

**Replace:**

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

**with:**

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $preFix = $this->getPrefix();
            $name .= Mage::helper('customer')->__($preFix) . ' ';           
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer_address', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

Copy:  /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

**Replace:**

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $name .= $this->getPrefix() . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

**with:**

```
public function getName()
    {
        $name = '';
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getPrefix()) {
            $preFix = $this->getPrefix();
            $name .= Mage::helper('customer')->__($preFix) . ' ';
        }
        $name .= $this->getFirstname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible() && $this->getMiddlename()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getMiddlename();
        }
        $name .=  ' ' . $this->getLastname();
        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible() && $this->getSuffix()) {
            $name .= ' ' . $this->getSuffix();
        }
        return $name;
    }
```

Copy /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Block/Address/Renderer/Default.php

**Replace:**

```
public function render(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract $address, $format=null)
    {
        switch ($this->getType()->getCode()) {
            case 'html':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML;
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF;
                break;
            case 'oneline':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE;
                break;
            default:
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                break;
        }

        $formater   = new Varien_Filter_Template();
        $attributes = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getAttributes();

        $data = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
            if (!$attribute->getIsVisible()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'country_id') {
                $data['country'] = $address->getCountryModel()->getName();
            } else if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'region') {
                $data['region'] = Mage::helper('directory')->__($address->getRegion());
            } else {
                $dataModel = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::factory($attribute, $address);
                $value     = $dataModel->outputValue($dataFormat);
                if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiline') {
                    $values    = $dataModel->outputValue(Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ARRAY);
                    // explode lines
                    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                        $key = sprintf('%s%d', $attribute->getAttributeCode(), $k + 1);
                        $data[$key] = $v;
                    }
                }
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $value;
            }
        }

        if ($this->getType()->getHtmlEscape()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->escapeHtml($value);
            }
        }

        $formater->setVariables($data);

        $format = !is_null($format) ? $format : $this->getFormat($address);

        return $formater->filter($format);
    }
```

**With:**

```
public function render(Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract $address, $format=null)
    {
        switch ($this->getType()->getCode()) {
            case 'html':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML;
                break;
            case 'pdf':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_PDF;
                break;
            case 'oneline':
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ONELINE;
                break;
            default:
                $dataFormat = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_TEXT;
                break;
        }

        $formater   = new Varien_Filter_Template();
        $attributes = Mage::helper('customer/address')->getAttributes();

        $data = array();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            //echo $attribute->getAttributeCode(); echo '<br />';
            /* @var $attribute Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute */
            if (!$attribute->getIsVisible()) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'prefix') {
                 $prefixopt = $address->getPrefix();
            }
            if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'country_id') {
                $data['country'] = $address->getCountryModel()->getName();
            } else if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'region') {
                $data['region'] = Mage::helper('directory')->__($address->getRegion());
            } else {
                $dataModel = Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::factory($attribute, $address);
                $value     = $dataModel->outputValue($dataFormat);
                if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'multiline') {
                    $values    = $dataModel->outputValue(Mage_Customer_Model_Attribute_Data::OUTPUT_FORMAT_ARRAY);
                    // explode lines
                    foreach ($values as $k => $v) {
                        $key = sprintf('%s%d', $attribute->getAttributeCode(), $k + 1);
                        $data[$key] = $v;
                    }
                }
                $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $value;
            }
        }

        $data['prefix'] = Mage::helper('customer')->__($prefixopt);

        if ($this->getType()->getHtmlEscape()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = $this->escapeHtml($value);
            }
        }

        $formater->setVariables($data);

        $format = !is_null($format) ? $format : $this->getFormat($address);

        return $formater->filter($format);
    }
```

Make sure you have added the translation words in your translation CSV.
I have successfully done this in Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: this one resolves the problem. tested with 1.9.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old threat, but I needed the answer and couldn't find it here. I found the answer myself, for the people who aren't familiar with Magento:

Copy System.xml from /app/code/**core**/Mage/Customer/etc/ to /app/code/**local**/Mage/Customer/etc/

Change in System.xml at the prefix label the show_in_store value from 0 to 1. You can now see the label in every store view and give it different values, thus translations.

NOTE: Prefix has a label for activating and a label for the options.

You can also use these values in the transactional emails.

Comment: This works? Afaik system.xml can not be "overwritten" by copying to local?

Comment: Fabian is right, I tried this and the file located at `/app/code/local/Mage/Customer/etc/system.xml` does not seem to overwrite the core file.